# OpenFileDialog, GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, .net

The "Open" and "Cancel" button aren't localized on the .Net's OpenFileDialog (always in English). Therefore I use GetOpenFileName with WinApi. It works, but there is a strange error:

- If the owner window of the dialog is not specified, the dialog is not modal, so the user can hide it without closing (I don't want this).
- If the owner is specified, "Open" and "Cancel" again in English always.

Here are some examples what I've experienced:

1. In .Net + Win7 the two buttons texts are always English, but everything else is localised: menu, hints etc..
2. Everything is the same with a MFC application using CFileDialog.
3. Default applications (eg. Notepad) are fully localised.
4. GetOpenFileName makes fully localised dialog, but only if I don't specify the owner window.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  However there is no .NET OpenFileDialog.  The class is a thin wrapper around the exact same Win32 GetOpenFileName call, and so the behaviour will be the same.

Comment: The native dialog uses the language of the Windows version you got.  A Danish version of Windows will display Danish text on the buttons.  You can localize your version of Windows only when you have the English Ultimate edition, install the appropriate language pack and change the system language.  Or obtain a localized version of Windows through an MSDN subscription.  There is rarely a point in doing so, your user will have purchased her own localized Windows version and will be happy with the button text.